# SQL Server 2005 won't update rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a SQL Server 2005 set up and has been running successfully for quite a long period of time without any issues.

As of this morning our website applications have been attempting to perform udpates on various rows. However, every time an update happens the data never gets updated in the database.

Our application's code hasn't been changed in any way, and there appears to be no errors of any kind.

Is there anything in SQL Server that can prevent updates from being performed on a database? Can the size of transaction logs prevent data from being updated on a SQL Server database? Or anything at all that can cause this strange behaviour?

Comment: Check the SQL Server log and the Application log for errors.  If SQL Server isn't throwing errors, run a SQL Trace with Profiler and see what exactly is hitting the database.

Comment: Use SQL Profiler to see exact sql statements executed by your app

Comment: Also please post the connection strings for the app and how you are verifying the data isn't being updated (removing passwords or other identifying info of course). Often this problem can be because the application is pointed at the wrong database, or is using deprecated features like `user instances` with `AttachDbFileName`.

Answer (score 1):

We had similar behaviour on one of our servers and it was due to the log file being on a hard drive that had run out of disk space - so worth checking that.

Also check that the Autogrowth limits haven't been reached:

[image]